# Iphone application crashes when poping to rootController of UITabBar tab

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar

I'm having this bug I can't figure out and it is making my head hurt. So, basically, in my iphone application I have UITabBar with some tabs each having UINavigationControllers inside.

Something like this:

```
    someViewController *someController = [[someViewController alloc] myInit];
    UINavigationController *someNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:someController];
    tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tab.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:otherNav, otherNav, evilNav, nil];
    [window addSubview:tab.view];
```

So to reproduce my "precious" bug I go like this:

```
click evilNav tab 
-> push tableListView (category list)
-> push otherTableListView (category items list) 
-> push someOtherView (single item)
-> popToRoot || popToController withindex:0 || click on evilNav tab again || pop to otherTableListView -> pop to tableListView
-> crash (with no notable error)
```

So if I go so far to someOtherView I can't go back to first tableListView (rootViewController) without application crashing. Meanwhile I can go to other tabs and then even click evilNav (when it is in otherTableListView or someOtherView state) without crashing.

What could be causing this problem? (If you need I will post more code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant really tell with out you posting a little more code, but if I had to take a guess I would say you are releasing something you should not be then trying to access is it again which usually crashes with no error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Commenting releases worked like charm and my application no longer crashes. No to figure out what exactly was wrong..

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

We need to see the code for the pushing and popping.  It seems like it's a memory issue though.  You're probably releasing the first viewcontroller when it's popped, even though you're not done with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the way you declare private members.

My answer is actually embedded in my question I posted here: [UINavigationController crash because of pushing and poping UIViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807301/uinavigationcontroller-crash-because-of-pushing-and-poping-uiviewcontrollers)