# iphone app crashes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, crash, ios-simulator

i am running my program using iphone simulator n at some point application crashes..but there is no error...just getting Debugging terminated in debugger console

how i can check  this what is the problem of crashes?

Comment: Have you tried running with breakpoints on?  Have you tried enabling NSZombies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about memory leaks?? If you are alloc-ing a lot of variables and not releasing them this can cause memory leaks. Which will in time cause the app to crash with a black screen.  Try running your app with the "Leaks" tool.  Go to Run -> Run with Performance Tools -> Leaks.  Go through everything you can in the app with this tool running and it will inform you of any memory leaks.

Here is a good link for information about using the Leaks Instrument:
http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

Also check your code!! If you know where its crashing go and check the code and make sure your doing everything you intend to!

Comment: thank u Matt, i will try this, also i have list, in list i am selecting on cell and UIActionSheet comes then i have to make selection (e.g. i press Edit)(1)I go to Edit View there are cancel and save bar items-->some times its running fine some time its crash when i press save or cancel(2)if its working fine n now i am back to my list again when i am selecting same cell for Edit option from action sheet its static i mean application is not crash only button is shown pressed n i have to quit iphone simulator....i have presentation next week, n i dont know how i can do this??

Comment: you are right its memory leaks problem, i solved one but second one not able to do...scenario : select record in list->actionsheet->select Edit option->now if i am editing and SAVE in Edit view 1st time no problem but 2nd times it crash as i am not releasing the object created at save time now -->if i am trying to release it its crash at very 1st time

Comment: you shouldn't release the variables until everything is said and done.  Look at where your calling the edit function and check to see what it actually does.  If it crashes and its not a memory leak then you might be passing parameters that aren't correct or calling a wrong method.

Comment: ok finally i got it..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807301/uinavigationcontroller-crash-because-of-pushing-and-poping-uiviewcontrollers

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into crash logs. You can find them in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter

Comment: i am looking for this ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter but i dont have, ~/Library/Logs/ there is no crashreports