# iOS filtered tableview navigation push UIView, then UIView back causing crash

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, pushviewcontroller

Did someone meet the same bothering issue? I cannot figure out the UIView will send release message to whom.

Many thanks for any advice.

My test code Strictly follow Apple tableView/Search example code guide. Initial TableView works perfect. and the filtered tableView is triggered to display in UISearchController -> searchResultsController, code is like below.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

...

        let tableController = self.searchController!.searchResultsController as! FilteredTableViewController
        tableController.datasource = self.tableData?.tableFilteredCellRecords
        tableController.navController = self.navigationController
        tableController.tableView.reloadData()
...
}
```

In the filtered tableView, Cell row display OK, then click any cell to trigger detail UIView display, code is like below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let record = self.tableData!.getFilteredTableRecord(indexPath.row)

    if(record != nil) {
        let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
        detailViewController.titleText = record?.title
        detailViewController.descText = record?.desc
        detailViewController.imgExist = record!.imgview

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: false)

    }
}
```

Then the detail UIView display well, but when click 'Back' button to return TableView, the App crash.

After enable Zombie, the debug report:

```
(lldb) 
Optional("A server with the specified hostname could not be found.")
2015-05-04 22:45:31.687 Swift_UI_programmatically[2057:419330] *** -[UIViewControllerWrapperView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fdefe0d8250
(lldb) 

0x102db5f49 <+489>:  callq  *0x3062a1(%rip)           ; (void *)0x0000000102b08000: objc_msgSend
0x102db5f4f <+495>:  jmp    0x102db5f72               ; <+530>
0x102db5f51 <+497>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x102db5f54 <+500>:  callq  0x102eaff58               ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
0x102db5f59 <+505>:  movq   %rax, %rcx
0x102db5f5c <+508>:  leaq   0x32cabd(%rip), %rsi      ; @"*** NSForwarding: warning: object %p of class '%s' does not implement forwardInvocation: -- dropping message"
0x102db5f63 <+515>:  movl   $0x4, %edi
0x102db5f68 <+520>:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x102db5f6a <+522>:  movq   %r14, %rdx
0x102db5f6d <+525>:  callq  0x102dfd000               ; CFLog
0x102db5f72 <+530>:  movq   0x34b0a7(%rip), %rax      ; NSInvocation._retainedArgs
0x102db5f79 <+537>:  cmpb   $0x0, (%rbx,%rax)
0x102db5f7d <+541>:  je     0x102db5fb1               ; <+593>
0x102db5f7f <+543>:  movq   (%r13), %rax
0x102db5f83 <+547>:  testb  $-0x80, 0x22(%rax)
0x102db5f87 <+551>:  je     0x102db5fb1               ; <+593>
0x102db5f89 <+553>:  movq   0x34b080(%rip), %rcx      ; NSInvocation._frame
0x102db5f90 <+560>:  movq   (%rbx,%rcx), %rcx
0x102db5f94 <+564>:  movl   0x1c(%rax), %edx
0x102db5f97 <+567>:  movzbl 0x20(%rax), %esi
0x102db5f9b <+571>:  addq   %rdx, %rsi
0x102db5f9e <+574>:  movq   (%r15,%rsi), %rdi
0x102db5fa2 <+578>:  movq   (%rcx,%rsi), %rsi
0x102db5fa6 <+582>:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x102db5fa9 <+585>:  movl   0x10(%rax), %edx
0x102db5fac <+588>:  callq  0x102eb04b0               ; symbol stub for: memmove
0x102db5fb1 <+593>:  movq   0x34b050(%rip), %rax      ; NSInvocation._retdata
0x102db5fb8 <+600>:  movq   (%rbx,%rax), %r15
0x102db5fbc <+604>:  movq   0x34a02d(%rip), %rsi      ; "methodReturnType"
0x102db5fc3 <+611>:  movq   %r12, %rdi
0x102db5fc6 <+614>:  callq  *0x306224(%rip)           ; (void *)0x0000000102b08000: objc_msgSend
0x102db5fcc <+620>:  movzbl (%rax), %eax
0x102db5fcf <+623>:  cmpl   $0x44, %eax
0x102db5fd2 <+626>:  jne    0x102db6009               ; <+681>
0x102db5fd4 <+628>:  fldt   (%r15)
0x102db5fd7 <+631>:  jmp    0x102db6009               ; <+681>
0x102db5fd9 <+633>:  movq   %rax, %rbx
0x102db5fdc <+636>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x102db5fdf <+639>:  callq  0x102e60560               ; getAtomTarget
0x102db5fe4 <+644>:  movq   %rax, %r12
0x102db5fe7 <+647>:  movq   %r12, (%r15,%r14)
0x102db5feb <+651>:  movl   $0x400, %ecx
0x102db5ff0 <+656>:  xorl   %r8d, %r8d
0x102db5ff3 <+659>:  movq   %r13, %rdi
0x102db5ff6 <+662>:  movq   %r15, %rsi
0x102db5ff9 <+665>:  movq   %r15, %rdx
0x102db5ffc <+668>:  callq  0x102d4ed60               ; __invoking___
0x102db6001 <+673>:  cmpq   %r12, (%r15)
0x102db6004 <+676>:  jne    0x102db6009               ; <+681>
0x102db6006 <+678>:  movq   %rbx, (%r15)
0x102db6009 <+681>:  movq   %r15, %rax
0x102db600c <+684>:  addq   $0x18, %rsp
0x102db6010 <+688>:  popq   %rbx
0x102db6011 <+689>:  popq   %r12
0x102db6013 <+691>:  popq   %r13
0x102db6015 <+693>:  popq   %r14
0x102db6017 <+695>:  popq   %r15
0x102db6019 <+697>:  popq   %rbp
0x102db601a <+698>:  retq   
0x102db601b <+699>:  leaq   0x35638e(%rip), %rax      ; __CFOASafe
0x102db6022 <+706>:  cmpb   $0x0, (%rax)
0x102db6025 <+709>:  je     0x102db603b               ; <+731>
0x102db6027 <+711>:  movl   $0x15, %edi
0x102db602c <+716>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
0x102db602e <+718>:  xorl   %ecx, %ecx
0x102db6030 <+720>:  xorl   %r8d, %r8d
0x102db6033 <+723>:  movq   %r13, %rsi
0x102db6036 <+726>:  callq  0x102e30880               ; __CFRecordAllocationEvent
0x102db603b <+731>:  addq   $0xa, %rbx
0x102db603f <+735>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rdi
0x102db6043 <+739>:  callq  0x102eaff76               ; symbol stub for: sel_getName
0x102db6048 <+744>:  movq   %rax, %rcx
0x102db604b <+747>:  leaq   0x32c90e(%rip), %rdx      ; @"*** -[%s %s]: message sent to deallocated instance %p"
0x102db6052 <+754>:  movl   $0x3, %edi
0x102db6057 <+759>:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x102db6059 <+761>:  movq   %rdx, %rsi
0x102db605c <+764>:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
0x102db605f <+767>:  movq   %r13, %r8
0x102db6062 <+770>:  callq  0x102dfd000               ; CFLog
0x102db6067 <+775>:  int3   
->  0x102db6068 <+776>:  jmp    0x102db6167               ; <+1031>

0x102db606d <+781>:  movq   %r12, %rdi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

when changed viewController..

Answer (score 0):

After read many discussion in stackoverflow, finally get one helpful advice, and that really work. 'Don't push two viewControllers animated at the same time. Push the first one without animation and push the second one with animation. UINavigationController can't handle two animations at the same time'

[UINavigationController crash because of pushing and poping UIViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807301/uinavigationcontroller-crash-because-of-pushing-and-poping-uiviewcontrollers)

Finally, only change one line code: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(), set the animation as true. this bug is fixed. I Cannot believe this is iOS bug, or some unknown knowledge.